# How to deploy a node.js with redis on kubernetes?

Tags: node.js, redis, kubernetes, minikube

I have a very simple node.js application (HTTP service), which "talks" to redis. I want to create a deployment and run it with minikube.

From my understanding, I need a kubernetes Pod for my app, based on the docker image. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.9.1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I build the docker image with `docker build -t my-app .`

Next, I created a Pod definition for my app's Pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-app
    image: my-app:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
```

So far, so good. But from now on, I have no clear idea how to proceed with redis:

1. should redis be another Pod, or a Service (in terms of Kubernetes kind)?
2. How do I reference redis from inside my app? Based on whether redis will be defined as a Pod/Service, how do I obtain a connection URL and port? I read about environment variables being created by Kubernetes, but I am not sure whether these work for Pods or Services.
3. How do I aggregate both (my app & redis) under single configuration? How do I make sure that redis starts first, then my app (which requires running redis instance), and how do I expose my HTTP endpoints to the "outside world"? I read about Deployments, but I am not sure how to connect these pieces together.

Ideally, I would like to have all configurations inside YAML files, so that at the end of the day the whole infrastructure could be started with a single command.

Comment: FYI: The `EXPOSE` definition is deprecated but only used for documentation purposes (it provides no other useful capability). :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with all of the previous answers. I'm just trying to things more simple by executing a single command.

First, create necessary manifests for redis in a file say `redis.yaml` and service to expose it outside.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: node-redis
spec:
  ports:
  - name: redis
    port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: node-redis
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: node-redis
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: node-redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        # data volume where redis writes data
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data
          readOnly: false
      volumes:
      - name: data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: redis-data
---
# data volume
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: redis-data
  labels:
    app: node-redis
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
```

Next put manifests for your app in another file say `my-app.yaml`. Here i put the volume field so that you can use the data that stored by redis.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: node-redis
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-app
    image: my-app:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
    # data volume from where my-app read data those are written by redis
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data
      mountPath: /data
      readOnly: false
  volumes:
  - name: data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: redis-data
```

Now we can use the following bash file `my-app.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

kubectl create -f redis.yaml

pod_name=$(kubectl get po -l app=node-redis | grep app-with-redis | awk '{print $1}')

# check whether redis server is ready or not
while true; do
  pong=$(kubectl exec -it $pod_name -c redis redis-cli ping)
  if [[ "$pong" == *"PONG"* ]]; then
    echo ok;
    break
  fi
done

kubectl create -f my-app.yaml
```

Just run `chmod +x my-app.sh; ./my-app.sh` to deploy. To get the url run `minikube service redis --url`. You can similarly get the url for your app. The only thing is you need a `nodePort` type service for your app to access it from outside of the cluster.

So, everything is in your hand now.

Answer (score 5):

I think I figured out a solution (using a Deployment and a Service).

For my deployment, I used two containers (webapp + redis) within one Pod, since it doesn't make sense for a webapp to run without active redis instance, and additionally it connects to redis upon application start. I could be wrong in this reasoning, so feel free to correct me if you think otherwise.

Here's my deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /srv/www
          name: redis-storage
      - name: my-app
        image: my-app:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
      volumes:
      - name: redis-storage
        emptyDir: {}
```

And here's the Service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-service
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: my-app-deployment
```

I create the deployment with:
`kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`
Then, I create the service with `kubectl create -f service.yaml`
I read the IP with `minikube ip` and extract the port from the output of `kubectl describe service my-app-service`.

Comment: One of the main reasons why you would separate your containers from running under one pod is for scalability. i.e.: If you have to scale your web app you'd end up with different redis instances.

Comment: thanks @yomateo - I wasn't precise in my original description - in case of my application this would be a desired situation :)

Answer (score 3):

I would run redis in a separate pod (i.e.: so your web app doesn't take down the redis server if itself crashes).

Here is your redis deployment & service:

deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: host-sys
          hostPath:
            path: /sys
      initContainers:
        - name: disable-thp
          image: redis:4.0-alpine
          volumeMounts:
            - name: host-sys
              mountPath: /host-sys
          command: ["sh", "-c", "echo never > /host-sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled"]
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:4.0-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 350m
            memory: 1024Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
```

service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    name: redis
  selector:
    app: redis
```

Since we've exposed a kubernetes `Service` you can then access your redis instance by hostname, or it's "service name", which is `redis`.

You can check out my kubernetes redis repository at https://github.com/mateothegreat/k8-byexamples-redis. You can simply run `make install` if you want the easier route.

Good luck and if you're still stuck please reach out!

Answer (score 1):

1. yes you need a separete `deployement` and `service` for redis
2. use kubernetes service discovery , should be built in , KubeDNS , CoreDNS
3. use readniness and liveness probes

Yes , you can write a single big yaml file to describe all the deployments and services. then:

`kubectl apply -f yourfile.yml`

or you can place the yaml in separate files and then do the :

```
 kubectl apply -f dir/
```

Comment: what would you put in the *.yaml files in order to complete what I already have for my-app Pod?

Comment: its for you to figure out

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read further the k8s docs, but in general re your questions raised above:

1. Yes another pod (with the relevant configuration) and an additional service depends on your use case, check this great example: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/configuration/configure-redis-using-configmap/
2. Using services, read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/
3. There are several ways to manage dependencies - search for deployment dependencies, but in general you can append them in the same file with readiness endpoint and expose using a Service - read more in the link in bullet 2