# Temporary failure in name resolution redis

Tags: kubernetes, redis

I have been learning Kubernetes lately. And I'm trying to use redis but I am getting the following error:

```
Error:Error -3 connecting to redis:6379. Temporary failure in name resolution.
```

I'm using:

```
  conn = redis.StrictRedis(host='redis', port=6379)
```

**docker composer**:

```
     redis: 
        image: redis:alpine 
        ports:
          - "6379:6379"
```

**redis-deploy.yml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-deploy
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:alpine
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
```

**service redis:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: redis
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    app: redis
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    protocol: TCP
```

**kubectl get svc**

```
redis            NodePort    10.152.183.209   <none>        6379:32649/TCP   7m31s
```

**EDIT:** the image is pulling from docker, here is one of the deployment files.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: greeter-client-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: greeter-client
  minReadySeconds: 10
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: greeter-client
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: greeter-client
        image: seancork92/greeter_client:latest
```

Comment: Where is that python code running?

Comment: I added a edit. it pulling from docker and within a container pod for each redis, server(thats shown in the edit)

Comment: How is this docker composer you mentioned related to kubernetes? Please explain your setup, what is running where. What's connecting to what. You also mentioned `greeter_client:latest` image, but when I pulled it I find out there is no code realted to redis in client code. Your description is very chaotic, please be specific, because right now all we can do is guessing.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you are exposing your Redis instance with a [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types). Kubernetes reserves a very specific range of [high-numbered](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) network ports for NodePorts to avoid conflicting with commonly used ports like 22 or, in this case, 6379 like Redis.

When you ran `kubectl get svc` the service that was returned indicates that Redis is being [port-forwarded](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#exposing-the-service) to the host on port `32649`. Therefore, when you perform your connection attempt against Redis you should be using this port instead of 6379. (Also ensure that your Firewall and network topology are properly configured as well).

So, where do we go from here? Well, it's hard for me to say. I am lacking information to tell both where your client connection is originating from and where your cluster is running. In the event that your client is within your cluster (AKA another Pod) you should look into provisioning a [ClusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) Service instead of a NodePort Service.

In the case where your client is external to your cluster, my advice to you is to look into how to provision [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) service types and [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resources in Kubernetes.

This will allow you to spin up dedicated IPs. From which you can serve your application on any port, hostname, or subdirectory without any issues. To do that, however, you will need to have both a LoadBalancer and Ingress [Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/controller/) installed as the Kubernetes API Server ships with neither.

If you are using a Cloud Provider it is likely that you already have a LoadBalancer Controller. Just simply request one and then `kubectl get svc` and see if it ever advances from the Pending state. If you are operating on bare metal, you can use a physical load balancer like an F5 Big IP. Or you can use a Virtual Load Balancer controller like [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/).

Two popular Ingress Controllers are [NGINX](https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx-ingress&oq=nginx-ingress&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l6j69i65.1552j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and [Istio](https://istio.io/faq/). The NGINX controller deals exclusively with ingress management while Istio deals with that as well as highly-configurable networking and enhanced security.

Let me know if you need any further information or help with this question. Always happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

I used the yaml file below for redis (that I got and modified a bit from [How to deploy a node.js with redis on kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031852/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-with-redis-on-kubernetes)):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: redis
  name: redis
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - 192.168.2.146
  selector:
    app: redis
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    nodePort: 32000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6379
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-deploy
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data
          readOnly: false
      volumes:
      - name: data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: redis-data          
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: redis-data
  labels:
    app: redis
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
```

After deploying with the yaml file, when you run `microk8s.kubectl get services`, you should a response like below:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.152.183.1     <none>         443/TCP          14d
redis        NodePort    10.152.183.114   192.168.2.146   6379:32000/TCP   14m
```

In my case, microk8s is deployed on a local VM that is on 192.168.2.146 (which is described in `externalIPs`. So with this setup I could access redis from both the local VM (CentOS) and from the parent machine (Windows). Also, if microk8s is deployed on a remote server like in my case, you also need to open port 6379 so your code can access it remotely. To test the connectivity from the VM I used the commands below:

```
echo PING | nc 192.168.2.146 6379
echo PING | nc localhost 32000
```

For both commands you should get the response:

```
+PONG
```

From Windows you can use PowerShell and use the command `tnc 192.168.2.146 -port 6379` to test connectivity. You should get a response like below:

```
ComputerName     : 192.168.2.146
RemoteAddress    : 192.168.2.146
RemotePort       : 6379
InterfaceAlias   : <alias>
SourceAddress    : <source_ip>
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```