# How can I debug oauth2_proxy when connecting to Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, nginx, oauth-2.0, proxy, oauth2-proxy

I'm new to Kubernetes, and I've been learning about Ingress. I'm quite impressed by the idea of handling TLS certificates and authentication at the point of Ingress. I've added a simple static file server, and added cert-manager, so I basically have a HTTPS static website.

I read that NGINX Ingress Controller can be used with oauth2 proxy to handle authentication at the ingress. The problem is that I can't get this working at all. I can confirm that my oauth2-proxy Deployment Service and Deployment are present and correct - in the Pod's log, I can see the requests coming through from NGINX, but I can't see what uri it is actually calling at Azure B2C. Whenever I try and access my service I get a 500 Internal error - if I put my /oath2/auth address in the browser, I get "The scope 'openid' specified in the request is not supported.". However if I Test run the user Flow in Azure, the test URL also specifies "openid" and it functions as expected.

I think that I could work through this if I could find out how to monitor what oauth2-proxy requests from Azure (i.e. work out where my config is wrong by observing it's uri) - otherwise, maybe somebody that has done this can tell me where I went wrong in the config.

My config is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - -provider=oidc
        - -email-domain=*
        - -upstream=file:///dev/null
        - -http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
        - -redirect-url=https://jwt.ms/
        - -oidc-issuer-url=https://<tenant>.b2clogin.com/tfp/<app-guid>/b2c_1_manager_signup/
        - -cookie-secure=true
        - -scope="openid"

        # Register a new application
        # https://github.com/settings/applications/new
        env:
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID
          value: <app-guid>
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
          value: <key-base64>
        - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
          value: <random+base64>
        image: quay.io/pusher/oauth2_proxy:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: oauth2-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4180
          protocol: TCP
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 4180
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4180
  selector:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: static1-oauth2-proxy
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cloud.<mydomain>
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: oauth2-proxy
          servicePort: 4180
        path: /oauth2
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - cloud.<mydomain>
    secretName: cloud-demo-crt
```

In my static site ingress I have the following added to metadata.annotations:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$request_uri"
```

I'm not 100% sure whether these annotations should always be set as such, or whether I should have varies these for B2C/OIDC, but they seem to go off to the proxy, it's just what the proxy does next that fails.

Note that the log does indicate that oauth2-proxy connected to B2C, indeed if the issuer uri changes, then it goes into a crash fallback loop.

There seem to be anumber of articles about how to set this up, so I'm sure it's possible, but I got a little lost. If somebody could help with the setup or ideas for debugging, that would be wonderful.

Thanks.

---

Now I'm able to reliably get a ?state= and code= to display in the browser window on the /oauth2/callback page, but the page reports Internal Error. oauth2_proxy is logging when it should now, and the log says:

[2020/06/03 21:18:07] [oauthproxy.go:803] Error redeeming code during OAuth2 callback: token exchange: oauth2: server response missing access_token

My Azure B2C Audit log howwever says that it is issuing id_tokens.

When I look at the source code to oauth2_proxy, it looks as though the problem occurs during oauth2.config.Exchange() - which is in the goloang library - I don't know what that does, but I don't think that it works properly with Azure B2c. Does anybody have an idea how I can progress from here?

Thanks.

Mark

Comment: The code for golang/x/exchange::config.Exchange shows that it doesn't apply the Client_Id to the TokenUrl in the oidc discovery. Azure B2C does not have client_id as a part of the Url, so I may look at this later on today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I resorted to compiling and debugging the proxy app in VSCode. I ran a simple NGINX proxy to supply TLS termination to the proxy to allow the Azure B2C side to function. It turns out that I had got a lot of things wrong. Here are a list of problems that I resolved in the hope that somebody else might be able to use this to run their own oauth_proxy with Azure B2C.

When attached to a debugger, it is clear that oauth2_proxy reads the token and expects to fin, in turn access_token, then id_token, it then requires (by default) the "email" claim.

To get an "access_token" to return, you have to request access to some resource. Initially I didn't have this. In my yaml file I had:

```
    - --scope=openid
```

Note: do not put quotation marks around your scope value in YAML, because they are treaded as a part of the requested scope value!

I had to set up a "read" scope in Azure B2C via "App Registrations" and "Expose an API". My final scope that worked was of the form:

```
    - --scope=https://<myspacename>.onmicrosoft.com/<myapiname>/read openid
```

You have to make sure that both scopes (read and openid) go through together, otherwise you don't get an id_token. If you get an error saying that you don't have an id_token in the server response, make sure that both values are going through in a single use of the --scope flag.

Once you have access_token and id_token, oauth2_proxy fails because there is no "email" claim. Azure B2C has an "emails" claim, but I don't think that can be used. To get around this, I used the object id instead, I set:

```
    - --user-id-claim=oid
```

The last problem I had was that no cookies were being set in the browser. I did see an error that the cookie value itself was too long in the oauth2-proxy output, and I removed the "offline_access" scope and that message went away. There were still not cookies in the browser however.

My NGinX ingress log did however have a message that the Headers were more than 8K, and NGinX was reporting a 503 error because of this.

In the oauth2-proxy documents, there is a description that a Redis store should be used if your cookie is long - it specifically identifies Azure AD cookies as being long enough to warrant a Redis solution.

I installed a single node Redis to test (unhardened) using a YAML config from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53052122/2048821 - The --session-store-type=redis and --redis-connection-url options must be used.

The final Service/Deployment for my oauth2_proxy look like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --provider=oidc
        - --email-domain=*
        - --upstream=file:///dev/null
        - --http-address=0.0.0.0:4180
        - --redirect-url=https://<myhost>/oauth2/callback
        - --oidc-issuer-url=https://<mynamespane>.b2clogin.com/tfp/<my-tenant>/b2c_1_signin/v2.0/
        - --cookie-secure=true
        - --cookie-domain=<myhost>
        - --cookie-secret=<mycookiesecret>
        - --user-id-claim=oid
        - --scope=https://<mynamespace>.onmicrosoft.com/<myappname>/read openid
        - --reverse-proxy=true
        - --skip-provider-button=true
        - --client-id=<myappid>
        - --client-secret=<myclientsecret>
        - --session-store-type=redis
        - --redis-connection-url=redis://redis:6379

        # Register a new application
        image: quay.io/pusher/oauth2_proxy:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: oauth2-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4180
          protocol: TCP

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 4180
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4180
  selector:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
```

Hope that this saves somebody a lot of time.

Mark

Comment: Is <my-tenant> in --oidc-issuer-url Directory (tenant) ID guid that can be found in Identity Experience Framework | App registrations when opening individual application?

Comment: What is /tfp/ in oidc-issuer-url ? I’ve noticed that it is referenced in many (old?) posts, but current [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#endpoints) doesn’t include it, e.g. https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/token

Answer (score 2):

I tried to follow the [Mark Rabjohn’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148502/how-can-i-debug-oauth2-proxy-when-connecting-to-azure-b2c/61259884#61259884) , but was getting errors like

> oidc: issuer did not match the issuer returned by provider, expected
> "https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/tfp/c5b28ff6-f360-405b-85d0-8a87b5783d3b/B2C_1A_signin/v2.0/"
> got
> "https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/c5b28ff6-f360-405b-85d0-8a87b5783d3b/v2.0/“
> ( no policy name in the url)

It is a known issue (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/212724/oidc-should-the-provider-have-the-same-address-as-the-issuer)

> I'm aware that a few of the mainstream providers such as Microsoft
> doesn't strictly follow this pattern but you'll have to take it up
> with them, or consider the workarounds given by the OIDC library.

Fortunately  [oauth2-proxy supports](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/oauth_provider/#skip-oidc-discovery)
--skip-oidc-discovery parameter:
bypass OIDC endpoint discovery. --login-url, --redeem-url and --oidc-jwks-url must be configured in this case.

The example of parameters is the following:

```
- --skip-oidc-discovery=true
- --login-url=https://<mynamespace>.b2clogin.com/<mynamespace>.onmicrosoft.com/
      b2c_1a_signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
- --redeem-url=https://<mynamespace>.b2clogin.com/<mynamespace>.onmicrosoft.com/
      b2c_1a_signin/oauth2/v2.0/token
- --oidc-jwks-url=https://<mynamespace>.b2clogin.com/<mynamespace>.onmicrosoft.com/
      b2c_1a_signin/discovery/v2.0/keys
```

To create **scope** I had to set up  Application ID URI in Azure B2C via "App Registrations" and "Expose an API".
(e.g see  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-web-api-dotnet?tabs=app-reg-ga#configure-scopes).
I also have to grant admin permissions as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-api-application?tabs=app-reg-ga#grant-permissions (see also [Application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation in Azure AD B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65509170/application-does-not-have-sufficient-permissions-against-this-web-resource-to-pe))

```
- —scope=https://<mynamespace>.onmicrosoft.com/<myappname>/<scopeName> openid
```

You also should specify

```
- —oidc_issuer_url=https://<mynamespace>.b2clogin.com/<TenantID>/v2.0/
```

Using Directory/tenantId in oidc_issuer_url satifies validation in callback/redeem stage, and you don't need to set useinsecure_oidc_skip_issuer_verification=true.

Also note that **redirect-url**=https:///oauth2/callback should be registered in AAD B2C as application Redirect URI( navigate  in Application Overview pane to Redirect URIs link)

Comment: Hi Michael, I didn't notice your previous comments, but I do like this solution which allows precise setup.. FYI, if you want to see the URL style that includes /tfp/ it can be found in the Azure Portal's 'properties' page for each user flow under 'Issuer (iss) claim" drop down. The /tfp/ version can be selected.

Comment: I also have a branch of oauth2-proxy (from V5 I think) that allows inclusion of automated redirection based on errors in callbacks. This allows oauth2-proxy to automatically chain B2C workflows together (like from sign in to recover password). https://github.com/IntegratedArts/oauth2-proxy/tree/custom-error-redirect - I hope to update this to the latest version in the coming weeks and hopefully get it accepted into the main project.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information by [Mark Rabjohn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61259884/199848) and [Michael Freidgeim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66580887/199848) I also got (after hours of trying) a working integration with Azure AD B2C. Here is a configuration to reproduce a working setup, using docker-compose for testing it out locally:

#### Local setup

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  oauth2proxy:
    image: quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:latest
    command: >
      --provider=oidc
      --email-domain=*
      --upstream=http://web
      --http-address=0.0.0.0:9000
      --redirect-url=http://localhost:9000
      --reverse-proxy=true
      --skip-provider-button=true
      --session-store-type=redis
      --redis-connection-url=redis://redis:6379
      --oidc-email-claim=oid
      --scope="https://<mynamepsace>.onmicrosoft.com/<app registration uuid>/read openid"
      --insecure-oidc-skip-issuer-verification=true
      --oidc-issuer-url=https://<mynamespace>.b2clogin.com/<mynamepsace>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy>/v2.0/
    environment:
      OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID: "<app registration client id>"
      OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET: "<app registration client secret>"
      OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET: "<secret follow oauth2-proxy docs to create one>"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    links:
      - web
  web:
    image: kennethreitz/httpbin
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
```

The important bits here are these options:

```yaml
--oidc-email-claim=oid
--scope="https://<mynamepsace>.onmicrosoft.com/<app registration uuid>/read openid"
--insecure-oidc-skip-issuer-verification=true
--oidc-issuer-url=https://<mynamespace>.b2clogin.com/<mynamepsace>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy>/v2.0/
```

Using `--insecure-oidc-skip-issuer-verification=true` allows you to skip the explicit mentioning of the endpoints using `--login-url --redeem-url --oidc-jwks-url`.

`--oidc-email-claim=oid` replaces the deprecated option `--user-id-claim=oid` mentioned by [Mark Rabjohn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61259884/199848)

The scope is needed also just as Mark is explaining.

#### Azure AD B2C settings

These are the steps summarized that are necessary to perform in Azure AD B2C portal:

1. In the user flow, go to "application claims" and enable "User's Object ID". This is required to make the `--oidc-email-claim=oid` setting work
2. In the app registration, in "API permissions", create a new permission with the name `read`. The url for this permission is the value that you need to fill in for `--scope="..."`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about debugging, but according to your issue it's looking you are not passing header param.

**On static site ingress please add this one as well and try**

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: X-Auth-Request-Access-Token, Authorization
```

**Or this one**

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: Authorization
```

Comment: I haven't got this working so, I'll try your advice later today. I have read some articles about the Implicit flow. Do you also know whether 'Implicit flow' should be enabled or disabled for oath2_proxy?

Comment: Hi, Sure, Please let me know if it will not work. Regarding Implicit flow it is not recommended, Please make it disable. In implicit flow it will share the token on HTTP request(without handshake). So better not to enable.

Comment: It took a while to find some time for this, but I'm still not getting this to function. My oauth_proxy container is now logging, which has helped me fix some settings, but now every attempt results in being on the Callback page with a ?state=....&code=... which looks good. In the log though I get: [2020/06/03 21:18:07] [oauthproxy.go:803] Error redeeming code during OAuth2 callback: token exchange: oauth2: server response missing access_token - my Azure B2C audit log says that I am issuing Ids each time and the state and code changes - any ideas?

Comment: I've set up NGINX and OAuth2-Proxy on my local machine. It appears that my main problem is that I had only requested scopes for "openid offline_access" - you also need  to ask for permissions on a specific resource too before the tokens required. I've now been able to get oauth2_proxy to say "authenticated", but I had to change a lot of settings and I'm still not getting a cookie.