# AADB2C90205: Application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-app-registration

I have created the azure App registration(AD B2C) Programmatically using the Graph API. App is successfully created and i have added necessary scope and service principals. Once App created i have used the clientID to get the code using this

```
https://<tenant>.b2clogin.com/<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/<scope>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&scope=<scopeID>%20offline_access&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&client_id=<clientID>
```

and i have redirect to the signin page once signed i got the code as well. I have used the generated Code to get the refresh token using this API

```
https://<tenent>.b2clogin.com/<tenent>.onmicrosoft.com/<scope>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

But i got this Error

> {
> "error": "invalid_grant",
> "error_description": "AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the
> operation.\r\nCorrelation ID:
> \r\nTimestamp: 2023-11-09
> 17:20:12Z\r\n" }

I don't know how to give the access for read and write like user.read and user.writeAll programmatically using rest API.

Thank you for any guidance or insights on this matter.

Few Additional info

To update the scope i used

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/appObjId/
{
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To post the service princepal

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals
{
    "appId"A
}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Call Graph API or web API?

Comment: I getting the error while calling the refresh token API 
"https://<tenent>.b2clogin.com/<tenent>.onmicrosoft.com/<scope>/oauth2/v2.0/token"
Error:{"error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.\r\nCorrelation ID: \r\nTimestamp: 2023-11-09 17:20:12Z\r\n" }

Comment: {"requiredResourceAccess": [{
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Offline_access and OpenID. Are you not passing and API scope?

Comment: No i'm passing  [ { "id": "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182", "type": "Scope" }, { "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e", "type": "Scope" } ] } ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255905/discussion-between-rukmini-and-shanthi-b).

Answer (score 0):

The error ***"AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation"*** usually occurs if the Azure AD B2C application doesn't have permissions granted to perform the action.

Granted API permissions:

[image]

Generated auth-code:

```json
https://b2caadtenant.b2clogin.com/b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&scope=offline_access openid&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&client_id=ClientID
```

[image]

I generated **tokens** using below parameters:

```json
https://b2caadtenant.b2clogin.com/b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:offline_access openid
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

If you want to **scope as API** then grant API permissions like below:

[image]

Generated auth-code by using below endpoint:

```json
https://b2caadtenant.b2clogin.com/b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&scope=https://b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/APIID/user.readapi offline_access &redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&client_id=ClientID
```

[image]

Generated **tokens** via Postman using below parameters:

```json
https://b2caadtenant.b2clogin.com/b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SUSI/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/APIID/user.readapi offline_access openid
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

Make sure to add API permissions based on your requirement and grant admin consent as I can see you are passing scope as
`https://<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/node-api/<tenant>.Read offline_access openid` while generating tokens but granted only `openid` and `offline_access` scopes to the Application.

**UPDATE:** To grant API permissions openid and offline access check below:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/appObjId/
{
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

To grant Admin consent use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID` and run in browser, sign-in as admin and accept consent

**Reference:**

[reactjs - Application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation in Azure AD B2C - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65509170/application-does-not-have-sufficient-permissions-against-this-web-resource-to-pe) by Carl Zhao

Comment: How to grant the scope like offline_access, openid using Graph Rest API.

Comment: Check the UPDATED answer

Comment: I already did it but it is creating the scope like offline_access & openid but not granted.

Comment: To grant Admin consent use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID` and run in browser, sign-in as admin and accept consent

Comment: Try this https://winsmarts.com/how-to-grant-admin-consent-to-an-api-programmatically-e32f4a100e9d